# proof of the the prior predicative distribution

Tags: probability, bayesian, mathematical-statistics

According to [wikipedia,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_inference) the posterior predicative distribution is

$p(\tilde x | X) = \int p(x | \theta) p(\theta | X) d\theta$

How does one reach at the given equality?

I have

$p(\tilde x | X) = \int p(\tilde x,\theta |X) d\theta = \int p(\tilde x | \theta, X) p(\theta| X) d\theta$ where I use that $p(\tilde x, \theta, X) = p(X) p(\theta|X) p(\tilde x|\theta, X)$ but this is not consistent with the given formula.

Sorry I realized that I made a terrible mistake in the original description after looking at the comment and the answer, and now I have corrected.

Comment: As α is fixed on both sides, for operational simplicity, ignore it, So p(x) must equal the ∫ p(x|θ)p(θ)dθ but p(x|θ)p(θ) = p(x,θ). So now, we are looking at  ∫ p(x,θ))dθ, that is, we are integrating out the θ, which leaves just p(x) (or, more precisely, p(x|α)) as was to be proved.

Comment: are you saying that $\alpha$ is not a random variable?

Answer (score 6):

This is because the variable $\alpha$ only appears in the prior, not the likelihood. So $p(x|\theta,\alpha)=p(x|\theta)$.
The term hyper-parameter is used to describe this.

**update due to changed question**

This property is normally due to conditional independence, where the new data only depends on old data via the common parameters. A classic example is $(y_i|\theta)\sim Bernoulli(\theta)$. If you knew $\theta$ then any other data $y_{i+1},y_{i+2},...$ are irrelevant for inference about $y_i$. So you have say $Pr(y_i=1|\theta)=\theta$. But when you *don't know* $\theta$ this is when the other data are relevant and useful, because the give information about $\theta$.

Comment: Thank you for answering. but I do not quite get that. In the case that I encountered, $\alpha$ is some data that can be observed, I cannot see why $p(x|\theta, \alpha) = p(x, \theta)$ from a purely mathematical point of view. Are you saying that $x$ and $\alpha$ are independent?

Comment: Now that I think about it, they are indeed independent because the data is assumed to be drawn independently, and $x$ is the current observation while $\alpha$ is the previous observation.